# Same data on different pages displays differently in Power BI

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax

I am working on a report in Power BI Desktop.

On a page1 I have a table with Month and TotalPremium for each month. Data displays correctly:

[image]

Page2 I have the same table but TotalPremium displays incorrectly.

[image]

Page3 same table and Premiums shows correctly again.

[image]

I have the same filters, same data parameters. Why its acting this way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just have to delete and recreate visuals again sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had a date range slider on each page. When I refreshed the data behind my visuals, the date selected on one of my pages stayed stuck on an old date while the other one updated properly. I manually wiggled the slider and all the visuals fixed themselves.